# Remotely force a defragmentation

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-xp, defragmentation

First, the computers are of around 21 Win 7 Machines and 29 Win XP machines.  The DC is a Win2k8 server and the Mail server is Win2k3

I need to force a remote defragmentation on roughly 50 computers.  They have been complaining of slow performance and were recently plagued with a virus.  It is impractical to physically go there and start 50 of these as it would have to be after hours.  Is there a way to remotely send a command to each PC that will either create a scheduled tasks to kick it off or just force a defrag all together?

Comment: Ryan Riles nailed the answer, but if you have a bunch of virus-infected computers, you should consider re-imaging them.  Only way to be sure you got it all.  And your image should have less fragmentation too, so it's killing two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are going to be a number of different ways to accomplish this, but the first thing that comes to mind is to write a script to use PsExec to run defrag.exe on each PC.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7 why are you bothering to force a defrag?  Windows 7 by default defrags all hard drives on a periodic schedule.